# finditer not giving location

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to look through ChIP-seq peaks to find how far apart the consensus sites are, I plan on doing this using finditer (please tell me if there is a better way). The problem I am having is that I can not get finditer to give me an actual location.

Using the example from http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#regex-howto

```
import re

p = re.compile('\d+')

iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers drumming, 11 ... 10 ...')


for match in iterator:

     print(match.span)
```

My output is NOT the locations, but rather

```
built-in method span of _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00B0B6E8>
built-in method span of _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00B63058>
built-in method span of _sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00B0B6E8>
```

Also, two of these appear to be the same.

I am using the Eclipse platform and, I think, version 3.2 but am not sure how to check (yes I am new to this ;) )

Thanks for your help,
Fran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing `()`.

```
 print(match.span())
 #               ^^
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\d+')
>>> iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers drumming, 11 ... 10 ...')
>>> for match in iterator:
...     print(match.span())
...
(0, 2)
(22, 24)
(29, 31)
```

Comment: Ahh.. That makes me feel quite silly. Fixed it right up. Thank you!